# I am constantly getting an error from bidirectional rnn

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I am preparing a chatbot based on a udemy course. I am getting this error very constantly. anybody can help me?

```
ValueError: Tensor("bidirectional_rnn/fw/fw/Const:0", shape=(1,), dtype=int32) must be from the same graph as Tensor("Equal:0", shape=(?,), dtype=bool).
```

---

```
def model_inputs():
    inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name = 'input')
    targets = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name = 'target')
    lr = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name = 'learning_rate')
    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name = 'keep_prob')
    return inputs, targets, lr, keep_prob

# Preprocessing the targets
def preprocess_targets(targets, word2int, batch_size):
    left_side = tf.fill([batch_size, 1], word2int['<SOS>'])
    right_side = tf.strided_slice(targets, [0,0], [batch_size, -1], [1,1])
    preprocessed_targets = tf.concat([left_side, right_side], 1)
    return preprocessed_targets

# Creating the Encoder RNN
def encoder_rnn(rnn_inputs, rnn_size, num_layers, keep_prob, sequence_length):
    lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size)
    lstm_dropout = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm, input_keep_prob = keep_prob)
    encoder_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_dropout] * num_layers)
    encoder_output, encoder_state = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw = encoder_cell,
                                                                    cell_bw = encoder_cell,
                                                                    sequence_length = sequence_length,
                                                                    inputs = rnn_inputs,
                                                                    dtype = tf.float32)
    return encoder_state

# Decoding the training set
def decode_training_set(encoder_state, decoder_cell, decoder_embedded_input, sequence_length, decoding_scope, output_function, keep_prob, batch_size):
    attention_states = tf.zeros([batch_size, 1, decoder_cell.output_size])
    attention_keys, attention_values, attention_score_function, attention_construct_function = tf.contrib.seq2seq.AttentionWrapper(cell,attention_mechanism,attention_size,cell_input_fn=None,probability_fn=None,output_attention=True,name=None)
#attention_states, attention_option = "bahdanau", num_units = decoder_cell.output_size)
    training_decoder_function = tf.contrib.seq2seq.attention_decoder_fn_train(encoder_state[0],
                                                                              attention_keys,
                                                                              attention_values,
                                                                              attention_score_function,
                                                                              attention_construct_function,
                                                                              name = "attn_dec_train")
    decoder_output, decoder_final_state, decoder_final_context_state = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_rnn_decoder(decoder_cell,
                                                                                                              training_decoder_function,
                                                                                                              decoder_embedded_input,
                                                                                                              sequence_length,
                                                                                                              scope = decoding_scope)
    decoder_output_dropout = tf.nn.dropout(decoder_output, keep_prob)
    return output_function(decoder_output_dropout)

# Decoding the test/validation set
def decode_test_set(encoder_state, decoder_cell, decoder_embeddings_matrix, sos_id, eos_id, maximum_length, num_words, decoding_scope, output_function, keep_prob, batch_size):
    attention_states = tf.zeros([batch_size, 1, decoder_cell.output_size])
    attention_keys, attention_values, attention_score_function, attention_construct_function = tf.contrib.seq2seq.DynamicAttentionWrapper(attention_states, attention_option = "bahdanau", num_units = decoder_cell.output_size)
    test_decoder_function = tf.contrib.seq2seq.attention_decoder_fn_inference(output_function,
                                                                              encoder_state[0],
                                                                              attention_keys,
                                                                              attention_values,
                                                                              attention_score_function,
                                                                              attention_construct_function,
                                                                              decoder_embeddings_matrix,
                                                                              sos_id,
                                                                              eos_id,
                                                                              maximum_length,
                                                                              num_words,
                                                                              name = "attn_dec_inf")
    test_predictions, decoder_final_state, decoder_final_context_state = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_rnn_decoder(decoder_cell,
                                                                                                                test_decoder_function,
                                                                                                                scope = decoding_scope)
    return test_predictions

# Creating the Decoder RNN
def decoder_rnn(decoder_embedded_input, decoder_embeddings_matrix, encoder_state, num_words, sequence_length, rnn_size, num_layers, word2int, keep_prob, batch_size):
    with tf.variable_scope("decoding") as decoding_scope:
        lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size)
        lstm_dropout = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm, input_keep_prob = keep_prob)
        decoder_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_dropout] * num_layers)
        weights = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev = 0.1)
        biases = tf.zeros_initializer()
        output_function = lambda x: tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(x,
                                                                      num_words,
                                                                      None,
                                                                      scope = decoding_scope,
                                                                      weights_initializer = weights,
                                                                      biases_initializer = biases)
        training_predictions = decode_training_set(encoder_state,
                                                   decoder_cell,
                                                   decoder_embedded_input,
                                                   sequence_length,
                                                   decoding_scope,
                                                   output_function,
                                                   keep_prob,
                                                   batch_size)
        decoding_scope.reuse_variables()
        test_predictions = decode_test_set(encoder_state,
                                           decoder_cell,
                                           decoder_embeddings_matrix,
                                           word2int['<SOS>'],
                                           word2int['<EOS>'],
                                           sequence_length - 1,
                                           num_words,
                                           decoding_scope,
                                           output_function,
                                           keep_prob,
                                           batch_size)
    return training_predictions, test_predictions

# Building the seq2seq model
def seq2seq_model(inputs, targets, keep_prob, batch_size, sequence_length, answers_num_words, questions_num_words, encoder_embedding_size, decoder_embedding_size, rnn_size, num_layers, questionswords2int):
    encoder_embedded_input = tf.contrib.layers.embed_sequence(inputs,
                                                              answers_num_words + 1,
                                                              encoder_embedding_size,
                                                              initializer = tf.random_uniform_initializer(0, 1))
    encoder_state = encoder_rnn(encoder_embedded_input, rnn_size, num_layers, keep_prob, sequence_length)
    preprocessed_targets = preprocess_targets(targets, questionswords2int, batch_size)
    decoder_embeddings_matrix = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([questions_num_words + 1, decoder_embedding_size], 0, 1))
    decoder_embedded_input = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(decoder_embeddings_matrix, preprocessed_targets)
    training_predictions, test_predictions = decoder_rnn(decoder_embedded_input,
                                                         decoder_embeddings_matrix,
                                                         encoder_state,
                                                         questions_num_words,
                                                         sequence_length,
                                                         rnn_size,
                                                         num_layers,
                                                         questionswords2int,
                                                         keep_prob,
                                                         batch_size)
    return training_predictions, test_predictions




########## PART 3 - TRAINING THE SEQ2SEQ MODEL ##########

# Setting the Hyperparameters
epochs = 100
batch_size = 64
rnn_size = 512
num_layers = 3
encoding_embedding_size = 512
decoding_embedding_size = 512
learning_rate = 0.01
learning_rate_decay = 0.9
min_learning_rate = 0.0001
keep_probability = 0.5

# Defining a session
tf.reset_default_graph()
session = tf.InteractiveSession()

# Loading the model inputs
inputs, targets, lr, keep_prob = model_inputs()

# Setting the sequence length
sequence_length = tf.placeholder_with_default(25, None, name = 'sequence_length')

# Getting the shape of the inputs tensor
input_shape = tf.shape(inputs)

# Getting the training and test predictions
training_predictions, test_predictions = seq2seq_model(tf.reverse(inputs, [-1]),
                                                       targets,
                                                       keep_prob,
                                                       batch_size,
                                                       sequence_length,
                                                       len(answerswords2int),
                                                       len(questionswords2int),
                                                       encoding_embedding_size,
                                                       decoding_embedding_size,
                                                       rnn_size,
                                                       num_layers,
                                                       questionswords2int)

`
```

I am also getting this error when i am running my train/test predictions function

Comment: Could you simplify the model and see whether you can reproduce the error in a smaller setup?

Comment: Also, why do you `tf.reset_default_graph()` before creating the session? Try commenting it out and see what it does.